Failed to resolve variable outboundHeaders type expression --mule flow error at IDE (anypoint studio)
My IDE (Anypoint studio ) complains with the flow code and throw error message as below
But actually code is working, mvn build is also working. Does anyone have idea to get rid of this annoying error message at IDE?
Thanks alot
##Error Message ##
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Failed to resolve variable outboundHeaders type expression 'null' 
on element 'flow' custom metadata. It will be skipped from definition.
 Original error was: Failed to resolve type null in expression null..   
 rest_v1_service-orders.xml /closing-exp/src/main/mule/http_implementations
 imp_get:\rest\v1\service-orders    Message Flow Error


CODE
    <flow name="imp_get:\rest\v1\service-orders" doc:id="410c0ac0-3fde-4b50-88b5-6498f8fc3e51" >
        <ee:transform doc:name="init vars" doc:id="0244f123-c3b1-417b-b308-f48c534c097c">
            <ee:message />
            <ee:variables>
                <ee:set-variable variableName="operationType"><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
"api-rest"]]></ee:set-variable>
                <ee:set-variable variableName="operationStatus"><![CDATA["success"]]></ee:set-variable>
                <ee:set-variable variableName="businessEntityId"><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
vars.businessEntityId]]></ee:set-variable>
                <ee:set-variable variableName="businessEntity"><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
vars.businessEntity]]></ee:set-variable>
                <ee:set-variable variableName="businessEntityDetails"><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    companyCode: attributes.queryParams.companyCode 
}]]></ee:set-variable>
                <ee:set-variable variableName="originalAttributes"><![CDATA[attributes]]></ee:set-variable>
                <ee:set-variable variableName="noDataFound"><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
false]]></ee:set-variable>
            </ee:variables>
        </ee:transform>
        <ee:transform doc:name="request service orders" doc:id="a531d0ef-4935-4c71-a591-dacceeff1cd8">
            <ee:message />
            <ee:variables>
                <ee:set-variable variableName="requestHeader"><![CDATA[output application/java
---
{
    x_conversation_id: attributes.headers.'X-Conversation-Id'
}]]></ee:set-variable>
                <ee:set-variable variableName="queryParam" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
var companyCode = attributes.queryParams.companyCode 
---
{
    companyCode: companyCode
}]]></ee:set-variable>
            </ee:variables>
        </ee:transform>
        <json-logger:logger doc:name="[DEBUG] After http requeust" doc:id="e7d8d702-ded9-4fe8-b38f-e4fd50959c4d" config-ref="jsonLogger" message='#["params "]' tracePoint="BEFORE_REQUEST" priority="DEBUG" category="${glb.globalProperties.logging.category}" >
            <json-logger:content ><![CDATA[#[import modules::JSONLoggerModule output application/json ---
{
    queryParam: JSONLoggerModule::stringifyNonJSON(vars.queryParam)
}]]]></json-logger:content>
        </json-logger:logger>
    </flow>


screenshot


May be a bug in Studio. Be sure to use the latest version just in case. If so, report it as a bug and wait for a fix from MuleSoft. Note that this is not a place to track bugs.

@aled, thanks for quick reply, btw do you know where to file bugs for Studio? i will do that

If you are a customer contact support. Don't know for other users.
